# Unity ParticleSystem : StartSize - Random between two constants : How to access first value?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a very nice project of VideoJocking with real-time 3d/particle emitting with Unity and my Midi console and I am wondering if there are any ways to access the first variable of the properties that are ''Random between two constants''. They only return a float with the maximum value (Get and Set) but I can't find a way to get/set the first float.

Basically, I am using the keyboard inputs to change my variables:

```
if ((Input.GetKeyDown("s")) && (Input.GetKeyDown("g"))) {
        MyParticles.StartSize = 16;
    }
```

So I would have expected a Vector2 to be Min,Max but it is a single float.
Someone have an idea how I could get this working?

Thank's for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only know that If you select your particle effects you made there is a way to re-size them by using the min size and max size. I don't know if I understood your problem, sorry if not.

Maybe this links can help you:
(link)http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/524432/how-can-i-scale-shuriken-particle-system.html
(link)http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1109847/changing-the-radius-of-unity-53-particle-systems.html
(link)https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.SetParticles.html

Answer (score 0):

```
particalSystem.main.startSizeX
particalSystem.main.startSizeY
particalSystem.main.startSizeZ
```

all these types is MinMaxCurve, and that has property mode, the mode type is ParticleSystemCurveMode, this is what you want.